# CSS? Area in browser window has a small space at the edge. Example links

Tags: html, css, image, browser, space

I have this page which seems to display properly without the space in the top and top left between image and browser edge:

```
http://wideloadshipping.com/temp/register.php
```

Then I have this page which is pulling from the same CSS file that has the space at the top. What is wrong with my code?

```
http://wideloadshipping.com/temp/index.php
```

Comment: Please provide us some code or a jsfiddle. Were are here to help, not work for free.

Comment: I was asking for help. Helping another could be considered working for free.

Comment: No, helping is lending a hand with drywall not building the entire damn house.

Comment: Look at all the willing and happy helpers.

Comment: I would be more then happy to help if you provide the section of code, or all of it, so we don't have to isolate the problem ourselves. By just giving us a link you add even more work that we don't need to do to help you. I'm not angry with you or anything, I just want you to understand that on stackoverflow you need to help us so we can help you.

Comment: No problem Josh. I saw two ways to do it and choose this one. It wasn't for any particular reason other than the .css file only had 6 or 8 lines in it so it seemed like that wasn't the trouble hence css? in my initial post. Sloppy html was/is the culprit but I guess the css has priority over the html as it outputs properly now. Thanks for looking and I appreciate it. Had I taken the time to fully explain this we may have avoided the extra work issue as that was not my intention. I crawled over this sucker for 2 days before you all found the solution, thanks to stack and all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try zeroing out the browser default `body` element box model styling with:

```
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

You can reset (zero out) the defaults on all elements' box model `margin` and `padding` with:

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

Comment: Place this with the brackets in my html code or the css. If in html code then I assume elements box is: <BODY NOF="

Comment: Add into your CSS file. I wouldn't recommend appending anything to the body tag, that's not good form. Generally, you should separate styling (CSS) from markup (HTML). In your CSS file, style.css, add this to the very top line: `* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }`. If you don't have access to the CSS file, then you can apply the styling in the head section of the HTML, wrapped in style tags: `<style type="text/css">* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }</style>`

Comment: Thanks @WideloadShipping, glad to hear. Appreciate the feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

In the page that is correct, the margin of your  element have a value of zero. That makes the browser edge disappear.

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

The other one does not.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the CSS-File. You have

```
<BODY NOF="(MB=(DefaultMasterBorder, 159, 65, 174, 10), L=(templateLayout, 1100, 602))" BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000" LINK="#0033CC" VLINK="#990099" ALINK="#FF0000" TOPMARGIN=0 LEFTMARGIN=0 MARGINWIDTH=0 MARGINHEIGHT=0>
```

in your first file (note ***TOPMARGIN=0*** and ***LEFTMARGIN=0***). Add

```
margin:0px;
```

to the second ones css (body tag) and you should have the same effect.

Comment: Don't add the margin as a HTML-property. Add it to the the css-properties of your body.

Comment: They both have the same css. I added it and noting. Maybe this has something to do with the clearpixel.gif images?